# Azure ArmClient: Delete Azure App Registration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm currently using `Azure.ResourceManager` in C# to delete resources such as app services and databases in Azure. This works fine. See NuGet for reference. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager/1.0.0-beta.4

However, I want to do the same for deleting App Registrations from Azure, and cannot seem to find any documentation or examples online for how to do this. Do I require a separate library, or have I misunderstood something here?

Writing this in C#, using .NET 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with using **Microsoft Graph Rest API**

When deleted, apps are moved to a temporary container and can be restored within 30 days. After that time, they are permanently deleted

**`DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}`**

Example:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

await graphClient.Applications["{application-id}"]
    .Request()
    .DeleteAsync();
```

**Response: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content**

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed answer! 

So could I replace all of my code for managing the infrastructure (deleting app services, databases etc in Azure), with calls to this client?

Comment: To delete the application you try with this API. And  to call this API some permissions are required please check with document. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you